# Android Navigation Drawer should be centralized vertically

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-drawer

I have made my navigation drawer and it is working all fine , it is according to new design rules. but now I have a problem and after a couple of search I have found no note over it so far. So I end up with asking question here.

What I have done so far is some thing like

the picture shows you the demo , How ever I have made some thing like this its just the demo to give you people hint about what is header in the navigation drawer and where my menu items list lies 
 [image: this]

You can clearly see that there is a header in the navigation drawer and the menu item list beneath it .

**Problem 1**

now do to some reasons I have deleted the header , but my menu Items goes upwards to the top starting point. I know I can give margin up , but this is not the good way

Is there any good way I can just centralized them vertically ? I am wondering How to do it , Please Help me .

and **Problem 2** is , I want to minimize the distance and margin between the menu items and menu icons in navigation drawer How to do this. I have not seen any of the discussion over it.

Please help me in solving both problems.

Answer (score 3):

On screenshot you attached to your question, the navigation drawer doesn't look fine and according to the new desing rules :-/

Just have a look at the official guide: https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Luckly for you nowdays we are provided by Google with [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) that helps us with creating Navigation View (that replaces Navigation Drawer)

Here are links for you:

- official documentation, always a good read: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html
- nicely written blog post about Navigation View: http://antonioleiva.com/navigation-view/
- and last but not least, sample app using new Android Design Library: https://github.com/antoniolg/MaterializeYourApp

I know it's not the answer you were looking for, like "just change true to false in the line number 10" but stay assured that using official Navigation View is a way to go in modern Android world.

Comment: do you know any solution?

Comment: try using official Navigation View add see if still have your problem. now you are using custom code nobody knows...

Comment: I am using the official and  the picture i showed to You , is just demo

Comment: how about setting the transparent header over it

Comment: I have did it , but the header layout is taking touch , I have used , clickable=false, touchable=false  and other things to false whcih sense to touch , but still the layout is clickable and it shows the color dark on touch

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new [NavigationView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) from the Android Design Support Library in making your navigation drawer. NavigationView make s creating material design-compliant navigation drawer.
You can read about it at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Answer (score 1):

1. [Read these three articles](https://medium.com/android-news/navigation-drawer-styling-under-material-design-f0767882e692)
2. [Take a look at this code](https://github.com/Sottti/MaterialDesignNavDrawer)
3. [Use the design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)